# Guild member count not updating in tasks.loop in Discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am getting member count of a guild and outputting it in an embed after every hour. I am using tasks.loop in discord.py. The goal is that bot updates the member count after every hour. Problem that I am facing is that when bot runs for the first time, it finds the correct member count (lets say 5). But after the bot starts, any member leaves the guild (5-1 = 4), Bot doesn't find the correct number of members after the tasks.loop runs again. it still outputs 5. If I completely restart the bot, then it again outputs the correct number (4).

```
@tasks.loop(hours=1)
    async def update_embed(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
        client_channel = self.bot.get_channel(channel_id)
        member_count = client_channel.guild.member_count
        print(member_count)
```

Comment: Do you have the members intent enabled through code and dashboard?

Comment: If you take a look at the docs: `Due to a Discord limitation, in order for this attribute to remain up-to-date and accurate, it requires Intents.members to be specified.`